# Rename foreign key column not working in fluent api

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

I am trying to make a self referencing table

```
public class Category
{
    // PK
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    // Property
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    // FK
    public int? ParentCategoryId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Category> ParentCategories { get; set; }
    public virtual  ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; } // Product is defined later
}
```

and the configuration:

```
public class CategoryConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Category>
{
    public CategoryConfiguration():base()
    {
        HasKey(c => new { c.CategoryId });

        HasOptional(c => c.ParentCategories)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(c =>  c.ParentCategoryId );
    }
}
```

the idea is to use `ParentCategoryId` as the column name, but it's not working. Instead it generated a column named: `Category_CategoryId`.

I have tried to use `.Map(c => c.MapKey("ParentCategoryId"))` and the result was the same.

I don't think it is the reason of self referencing because the same thing happen in the many-to-many relationship :

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    public virtual  ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

and the `Product` configuration

```
public class ProductConfiguration:EntityTypeConfiguration<Product>
{
    public ProductConfiguration():base()
    {
        // Many-to-Many
        HasMany(c => c.Categories)
            .WithMany()
            .Map(p =>
            {
                p.MapLeftKey("ProductRefId");
                p.MapRightKey("CategoryRefId");
                p.ToTable("ProductCategory");
            });
    }
}
```

The table name is `ProductCategories` instead of `ProductCategory`
The foreign key is `Product_ProductId` and `Category_CategoryId`
They all not what is expecting.

how can i solve the problem? Please help.

Thank you!

---

**Update 1**

strange thing is if I define it via `DbModelBuilder`, then it works

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Category>()
            .HasOptional(c => c.ParentCategories)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.ParentCategoryId);
    }
```

the foreign key become `ParentCategoryId` as Expected.

Comment: First, don't call empty base(), it will be called by before running ctor in your class. Second, remove this HasKey(c => new { c.CategoryId });  and write just HasKey(c => c.CategoryId);
And about your question, what is the name of columns in db?

Comment: Hi, @Chase. Thank you for you suggestion. The foreign key column name is `Category_CategoryId`, I want to use `ParentCategoryId` as its name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, I made a mistake. I didn't hook the configuration into DbContext.

by add these into the `DbContext`, the columns are renamed as expected.

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CategoryConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ProductConfiguration());
    }
```